# spaCy model installation failed due to an EnvironmentError

Tags: python, ubuntu, spacy

I started getting this ERROR since I added this link to my requirements file which has more than 140+ requirements, I have tried to replicate it in my Local VM, without success, there it installs without a problem as well as my colleagues, we are all able to install it and run it without replication of this error on our VM's but on the server it is going constantly.
I have tried searching the google to the deep end but all I have found are metadata files missing which is not the case here.
I am wondering if I am missing something very basic that I am blinded to in this case ?
Thanks in advance

Server is Ubuntu 18.04

```
python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
```

```
pip3 --version
pip 20.3.3 from /webapps/USER/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

The Error:

```
(USER) USER@SERVER:/webapps/USER$ pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/de_core_news_md-2.2.0/de_core_news_md-2.2.0.tar.gz
Collecting https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/de_core_news_md-2.2.0/de_core_news_md-2.2.0.tar.gz
  Downloading https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/de_core_news_md-2.2.0/de_core_news_md-2.2.0.tar.gz (224.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 224.6 MB 4.2 kB/s

**ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-0fq5fn2b/5dc00eb62004e12b0ae78e1cfb7a2318260a1f5058048c4b04a0f2b9**'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was

```
wget https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/de_core_news_md-2.2.0/de_core_news_md-2.2.0.tar.gz
```

which then I installed using pip install {locally downloaded file}
worked like a charm.
I think this error occurs because of the Garbage Collector which cleans the tmp folder prematurely because of the long download time of the file.